# Access elements (e.g. UIView) which are generated on runtime

Tags: swift

For example, I generate some views like this:

```
func create() {
    let testview = UIView()
    parentView.addSubview(testview)
}
```

How can I access this specific element in another function?

```
func colorView() {
    testView.backgroundColor = .green
}
```

Creating a global is not possible in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't create a *global*, you create a *property*. It is global to (i.e. visible to) your different methods. That's called *scope*.

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    var myView : UIView?
    func create() {
        let testview = UIView()
        parentView.addSubview(testview)
        self.myView = testView
    }
    func colorView() {
        if let testView = self.myView {
            testView.backgroundColor = .green
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this works exactly the same as if `testView` were an outlet from the storyboard.

Comment: Hi Matt - thank you! I got it. How is it in the case where I create N elements?